# Squid TCP_Denied

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I'm trying to set up a basic proxy server.
I've tried allowing all but to no avail. Following is my squid.conf file

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow !Safe_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access allow  manager
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all
http_port 3128
```

As you see I've allowed all still it doesn't seem to work. The access logs show TCP_DENIED 403.

Comment: Are you sure you reloaded / restarted squid after configuration changes?

Comment: Yep, I did. @Khaled

Comment: For `http_access allow CONNECT !SSL_ports` and `http_access allow !Safe_ports` you're basically saying allow CONNECT from *anything other than* SSL_ports. Same thing for Safe_ports. You should change that *allow* to *deny*

Comment: @Mugurel Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Mugurel Any ideas what else I could do?